# Visual Studio npm install

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, jquery-ui, npm

I have an ASP.NET Core project. I want to use jQuery UI. I added "jquery-ui": "1.12.1" to package.json and it was installed successfully. node_modules/jquery-ui doesn't have a file like jquery-ui.min.js. There are gruntfile.js and many others. What I have to do now?

Comment: Whether the `jquery-ui-dist` works well for your application? If not, you could try to use the CDN reference to use JQuery UI. Besides, some of the JQuery UI widgets might not compatible with Bootstrap framework, so, you could also try to use the Bootstrap Framework to achieve the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `"jquery-ui-dist": "1.12.1"` to the `package.json`, then rebuild the project (tp install the package), finally, you will find the `jquery-ui.min.js` file from the `node_modules/jquery-ui-dist` folder.

[image]

Additional:

You could add the JQuery UI reference via the CDN:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```